# typeorm - Type '{Entity}' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<{Entity}>'

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, relational-database, one-to-many, typeorm

I am having some difficulties writing `typeorm` entities for a part of an existing database. This part looks like this:

[image]

In short: there's a `Brand` table, a brand can have more products, the system tries to find pairs of products of different brands. These pairs are stored in the `Comparison` table that has brand and product ids for each side of the comparison. Plus, it's involved an `XTable`, a brand can have more Xs and `Products` and `X` have a many to many relation.

I am trying to write the entities like this (just the relations):

```
@Entity('Brands')
class Brand {
    @OneToMany(() => XTable, (x) => x.brand)
    xs: XTable[];

    @OneToMany(() => Product, (product) => product.brand)
    products: Product[];

    @OneToMany(() => Comparisons, (comparison) => comparison.sideABrands)
    sideAComparisons: Comparison[];

    @OneToMany(() => Comparisons, (comparison) => comparison.sideBBrands)
    sideBComparisons: Comparison[];
}

@Entity('Comparisons')
class Comparison {
    @ManyToOne(() => Brand, (brand) => brand.sideAComparisons)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'SideABrandId', referencedColumnName: 'Id' })
    sideABrand: Brand;

    @ManyToOne(() => Product, (product) => product.sideAComparisons)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'SideAProductId', referencedColumnName: 'Id' })
    sideAProduct: Product;

    @ManyToOne(() => Brand, (brand) => product.sideBComparisons)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'SideBBrandId', referencedColumnName: 'Id' })
    sideBBrand: Brand;

    @ManyToOne(() => Product, (product) => product.sideBComparisons)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'SideBProductId', referencedColumnName: 'Id' })
    sideBProduct: Product;
}

@Entity('Products')
class Product {
    @ManyToMany(() => XTable, (x) => x.products)
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'Products_XTable',
        joinColumn: { name: 'ProductId' },
        inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'XTableId' },
    })
    xs: XTable[];

    @ManyToOne(() => Brand, (brand) => brand.products)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'BrandId', referencedColumnName: 'Id' })
    brand: Brand;

    @OneToMany(() => Comparison, (comparison) => comparison.sideAProduct)
    sideAComparisons: Comparison[];

    @OneToMany(() => Comparison, (comparison) => comparison.sideBProduct)
    sideBComparisons: Comparison[];
}

@Entity('XTable')
class XTable {
    @ManyToOne(() => Brand, (brand) => brand.xs)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'BrandId', referencedColumnName: 'Id' })
    brand: Brand;

    @ManyToMany(() => Product, (product) => product.xs)
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'Products_XTable',
        joinColumn: { name: 'XTableId' },
        inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'ProductId' },
    })
    products: Product[];
}
```

When I try to insert a record in the `Comparison` table, just doing

```
getRepository(Comparison).insert(...)
```

I get an error like:

```
Argument of type 'Comparison' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Comparison> | QueryDeepPartialEntity<Comparison>[]'.
  Type 'Comparison' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Comparison>'.
    Types of property 'sideAProduct' are incompatible.
      Type 'Product' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | QueryDeepPartialEntity<Product> | undefined'.
        Type 'Product' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Product>'.
          Types of property 'xs' are incompatible.
            Type 'XTable[]' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | QueryDeepPartialEntity<XTable>[] | undefined'.
              Type 'XTable[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<XTable>[]'.
                Type 'XTable' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<XTable>'.
                  Types of property 'products' are incompatible.
                    Type 'Product[]' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | QueryDeepPartialEntity<Product>[] | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

I cannot figure out where the error is because the relations look fine to me, if I cast the argument that I pass in the `insert` function as `any` it works.

Another question: do these tables look like normalized?

Comment: You don't need the `brandId` FK on comparison. Also, what is the use of the XTable?

Comment: It looks to me like the error is truncated. It should next tell you that `Type 'Product[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Product>[]'.` if it continues following this pattern. Are you certain that you have captured the entire error? It could be a typo or type mismatch in one of the properties of one of your side products…?